# Arabic text box

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio, dll

I have developed a web site: Some fields are entered in English while others are entered in Arabic language.

Now i wanna simplify the input operation for the user and want Arabic textbox as a DLL.

I have one but it works only with IE - not with firefox or google chrome ..

thanks so much..

How to enforce the user to write in Arabic? I mean moving the cursor directly without (ALT + SHIFT) keys every time when trying to change the language... If there is any way, property , DLL or what ever to do that...

Comment: Could you show us (the important parts of) the one you have? What exactly happens when it does not work?

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/salimfayad/pages/arabic-textbox-control.aspx

Comment: what you need it's not a DLL but a javascript library and definitely you can't deploy that DLL to user's machine, think of a user surfing your website on linux!

Comment: please Jani i wanna to understand the last point ,,is using DLLs is wrong in the state of web application or in this state only or what i don't understand this point..

Comment: how you solved your problem..could you answer your own question. Share your knowledge.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use this [mature javascript library](http://farsitype.ir) that works fine on firefox and IE, just add an attribute like lang='fa' or lang ='en' to your textbox and you're done, sure you can tailor it for your usage.

it's in persian and you can translate it with google to read the page.

I've done the adding attribute in client code and it's like this

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
                $().ready(function () {
                    $("input,textarea").each(function () {
                        $(this).attr("lang", "fa");
                    });
                });
  </script>
```

Comment: this is great but three more things::(1)how to add new attribute to server control i write `TextBox1.Attributes.Add("lang", "fa");` and then <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" lang="fa" ></asp:TextBox> and include my java script file but it doesnot work..(2)is this works with arabic letters as it works with farisi..(3)one drawback still i  need to click shift + alt to move from language to another this method just change the direction of writing .. and i still has the same problem..

Comment: I have an online working website using this. Take a look at http://afghan.moi.ir . I can send to you code snippets.

Comment: yeah thanks now it works ,, but it shows two blue buttons i donot want to show those buttons ,,in addition to that i wanna the default case for the input is the arabic .. i see your site ,,and nearly this what i wanna to do please show me the steps to hide the blue buttons and make some text boxes arabic and the other english ..thank u so much for your help

Comment: Download it from mentioned website http://afghan.moi.ir/Scripts/farsitype.js , I tailored it for my usage, e.g. I used the arabic YAE(ي) instead of default one, in addition to hiding buttons.

Comment: I know enough Arabic to get you pal, you're welcome. على الرحب والسعة as translated by Google. :-)

Comment: The links are outdated , could u give me new links please

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use direction and alignment properties of standard text box instead of an alternative one?

Comment: no direction for Textbox ,, u mean the diection of the form or HTML tag

Comment: but this will reflect on all the controls ,, and this not what i want as i have a mix of arabic and english inputs, so i think this DLL will be good ,, it works only on IE.

Comment: You may be able to control text direction/alignment with its container control such as DIV, etc.