# asp.net setting the language in TextBox

Tags: asp.net

I want to set the input language in TextBox in asp.net page. In this page I need one TextBox in hebrew and one text box in english.
I tried to replace the asp.net field with html input field where it is possible to set the lang attribute and it didn't set the language

Comment: See [**this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396297/how-to-change-textbox-input-language-in-web-application), it setting the language using Javascript. It might be helpful

Answer (score 1):

You can set it in jquery

```
$().ready(function () {
    $("#textbox").attr("lang", "he");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `lang` attribute for this purpose `asp:Textbox lang="he"`.

Comment: OP already said that he tried this as well. please read the question.